# Bar plot in loop for each observation

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Here is sample data where ID is a categorical variable.

```
ID <- c(12, 34, 560, 45, 235)
W1 <- c(0, 5, 7, 6, 0)
W2 <- c(7, 8, 9, 5, 2)
W3 <- c(0, 0, 3, 5, 9)
 
df <- data.frame(ID, W1, W2, W3)
df$ID <- as.factor(df$ID)
```

I want to draw five bar plots for each of these IDs using the frequency data for the three weeks `W1:W3`. In the actual dataset, I have 30+ weeks and around 150 IDs, hence the intention here is to do this efficiently. Nothing fancy, but `ggplot` would be ideal as I would need to manipulate some aesthetics.

How to do this using loop and save the images in one file(pdf)?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of problem is usually a data reformating problem. See [reshaping data.frame from wide to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format). After reshaping the data, the plot is faceted by `ID`, avoiding loops.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ID <- c(12, 34, 560, 45, 235)
W1 <- c(0, 5, 7, 6, 0)
W2 <- c(7, 8, 9, 5, 2)
W3 <- c(0, 0, 3, 5, 9)

df <- data.frame(ID, W1, W2, W3)
df$ID <- as.factor(df$ID)
df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], as.integer)

df |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-ID, names_to = "Week", values_to = "Frequency") |>
  ggplot(aes(Week, Frequency, fill = Week)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks()) +
  facet_wrap(~ ID) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

If there is a mix of week numbers with 1 and 2 digits, the lexicographic order is not the numbers' order. For instance, after `W1` comes `W11`, not `W2`. Package [stringr](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=stringr) function `str_sort` sorts by numbers when argument `numeric = TRUE`.
In the example below I reuse the data changing `W2` to `W11`. The correct bars order should therefore be `W1`, `W3`, `W11`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)

ID <- c(12, 34, 560, 45, 235)
W1 <- c(0, 5, 7, 6, 0)
W11 <- c(7, 8, 9, 5, 2)
W3 <- c(0, 0, 3, 5, 9)

df <- data.frame(ID, W1, W11, W3)
df$ID <- as.factor(df$ID)
df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], as.integer)

df |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-ID, names_to = "Week", values_to = "Frequency") |>
  dplyr::mutate(Week = factor(Week, levels = str_sort(unique(Week), numeric = TRUE))) |>
  ggplot(aes(Week, Frequency, fill = Week)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks()) +
  facet_wrap(~ ID) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly until I ran into a weird problem. I can't seem to manage how to put the weeks in order. For example, following your method, I get a nice bargraph, but the weeks are ordered as w1, w11:19, w2, w21:29, w3, w31:35, whereas the columns in the data are ordered in ascending order (w1:w35). Any lead on how to change this to the right order that follows the order of columns in the data?

Comment: @Tathagato Use package `stringr`, function `str_sort` with argument `numeric=TRUE` to put the unique values in order then coerce to factor with those values as factors. I will post code later on today

Comment: @Tathagato Done, see the edit.