# Create multiple bar charts depending on columns in R +ggplot

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, output, bar-chart

I'm trying to create multiple bar charts on the same output using columns as a separator, but I can only manage to create individual charts. It is now made as a function in order to do everything at once.

```
library("skimr")
library("tidyverse")
library("ggplot2")

V1 <- c(2,4,2,1,4)
V2 <- c(5,2,2,1,3)
V3 <- c(2,4,3,3,3)
V4 <- c(2,1,1,1,2)

df <- data.frame(V1,V2,V3,V4)

  lapply(names(df), function(col) {
  ggplot(df, aes(.data[[col]], ..count..), beside=TRUE) + 
    geom_bar() + 
    theme_minimal()+
    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 5), ylim = c(0, 5))+
    scale_x_discrete(labels=c("1" = "Not relevant", "2" = "2","3" = "3","4" = "4", "5" = "Highly relevant"), na.value = FALSE)
    })
```

Comment: See if [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73904130/bar-plot-in-loop-for-each-observation)  can help.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `patchwork::wrap_plots()` to plot the list of plots:

```r
library("ggplot2")

V1 <- c(2, 4, 2, 1, 4)
V2 <- c(5, 2, 2, 1, 3)
V3 <- c(2, 4, 3, 3, 3)
V4 <- c(2, 1, 1, 1, 2)

df <- data.frame(V1, V2, V3, V4)

lapply(names(df), function(col) {
  ggplot(df, aes(.data[[col]], ..count..), beside = TRUE) +
    geom_bar() +
    theme_minimal() +
    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 5), ylim = c(0, 5)) +
    scale_x_discrete(labels = c("1" = "Not relevant", "2" = "2", "3" = "3", "4" = "4", "5" = "Highly relevant"), na.value = FALSE)
}) |> patchwork::wrap_plots()
```

[image]